# Making a Stack "Dynamic" (C)

Tags: c

For an assignment I am to make code implementation fully dynamic. Our professor has provided us with a .c file that has several implementations like pop and push. Our pre-defined stack capacity is 128. We are to make it "dynamic" by checking if a push operation on our stack exceeds the pre-defined stack capacity.

I am sort of getting confused on how to do this. Can't I just include an if statement somewhere to check if the capacity is larger than the stack, and if it is, just simply allocate twice the capacity and create a new stack?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can add an `if` statement somewhere, but the `push` function is the best place to do that.  It's best because it is the one place where you know that more capacity is needed if you are at the current limit.

Comment: Please read this: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: "it is the one place where you know that more capacity is needed **`if`** you are at the current limit" You should post it as answer :'D

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Transferring a comment into an answer.*</sup>

Yes, you can add an `if` statement somewhere, but the `push()` function is the best place to do that. It's best because it is the one place where you know that more capacity is needed if you are at the current limit. Unless you have an 'increase capacity' function, only the `push()` function can ever need to grow the stack, so that's the only place where it is relevant to test whether you need to add more memory to the stack.

Note that you currently have a fixed upper-bound on the stack size.  You'll need to make that into a variable.  Remember to think carefully about the initialization conditions.